# How to disable custom Angular/Ionic page transitions when not using a mobile device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular/Ionic application that can run both on native and web (iPhone, Android, and Web). I set up a custom page transition animation, which looks good on mobile but weird on a large screen like on desktop, so I would like to disable these animations and have traditional page loading like you would see on a normal website.

My `app.module` imports contains the following line, overriding the traditional sliding animation:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({
  navAnimation: myTransitionAnimation
}),
```

I am aware of `Platform` and how I can use it to identify what the app is currently running on like so:

`this.platform.is('mobile')` but doing this is only available in an `app.component.ts` not in the `app.module.ts`...right?

**So basically my question is how to best do the following in my `app.module.ts` (pseudo code)**

```
IonicModule.forRoot({
    if(isMobileDevice) {
        navAnimation: myTransitionAnimation
    } else {
        animated: false //the key/value to disable transition animations
    }
}),
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Wrong no I did not :(

Answer (score 6):

I did it like this to disable page animations (in web and phone):

```
import { Animation } from '@ionic/core'
...
IonicModule.forRoot({
      backButtonText: '',
      mode: 'ios',
      navAnimation: (AnimationC: Animation): Promise<Animation> => { return Promise.resolve(new AnimationC()); }
 }),
```

Then I used  this to animate when opening a new page: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions

```
constructor(
    private nav: NavController,
    private transition: NativePageTransitions
  ) { }

  public push(url: string): void {
    this.transition.slide({ direction: 'up', duration: 350 });
    this.nav.navigateForward(url);
  }
```

Comment: Plese be careful that this plugin is deprecated and any App using it won't be allowed by Apple (to be submitted in the store) starting from the 1st of December 2020

Answer (score 0):

im using Ionic 5. I did it like.

```
import { Animation } from '@ionic/core'
...
IonicModule.forRoot({
      backButtonText: '',
      mode: 'ios',
      navAnimation: _ => new AnimationController().create()
})
```

And that did the trick for me.