# How to disable page transition animation in Ionic 4 / Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I’m using ‘routerLink’ to navigate to a new page and I was wondering how I could disable the page transition animation? I couldn’t find an answer to that simple question in the documentation or here (I only found answers to old versions of Ionic / Angular).

Could someone please point me to the right spot?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: are you asking about the transition animation, or do you want to disable/redirect the route?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I am asking about he animation.

Comment: See this, this worked for me for just disabling page animation rather than all animations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583239/how-to-disable-custom-angular-ionic-page-transitions-when-not-using-a-mobile-dev

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The parameter has changed from "animate" to "animated".

ie. in app.module.ts, do the following

```
IonicModule.forRoot({animated: false});
```

Comment: This also disables all animations for the entire app (modals, popovers, etc). Have you found a way to only disable it for ONLY the page transitions, and leaving everything else as is?

Comment: UPDATE: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583239/how-to-disable-custom-angular-ionic-page-transitions-when-not-using-a-mobile-dev

Comment: this prevents opening of modals and popovers on ios devices both app and browsers chrome, safari

Comment: Actually I need to remove transition only for Desktop/Laptop version. I mean for web only. for app it's fine.

Answer (score 26):

To *only* disable *page* transition animations, while leaving the rest of the animations alone, add `animated="false"` to the `<ion-router-outlet>`:

```xml
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content" animated="false"></ion-router-outlet>
```

Comment: Right syntax is [animated]="false".  Otherwise you get an error about string can't be assigned to boolean property.

Answer (score 15):

For people who want to control specified page only, you can use `NavController` of Ionic4 giving `{ animated: false }` as NavigationOptions.

```js
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,) {}

this.navCtrl.navigateForward(path, { animated: false });
```