# how to remove page transition in ionic 4 for web version only?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular7, ionic4

I have a `angular+ionic 4` application. I am developing for Android, iOS, and Web. Now while I go from one page to another page, default page transition is perfect for both Android and iOS, but when I run this in browser without choosing any device, (I mean without responsive, normally open url in new tab). It shows page transition effect same as of Android.

**I want to remove that page transition effect only from web.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable custom Angular/Ionic page transitions when not using a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583239/how-to-disable-custom-angular-ionic-page-transitions-when-not-using-a-mobile-dev)

Comment: Guys, your suggested answer is not my answer, below accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801993/11254862) is my answer. so this question is not duplicated, please. may be So many people has same question........

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but what about using the [Config api](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/config#by-component) to set it to null?

You can use the `forRoot({})` to pass settings in at startup but as the linked question figures out, the `platform` code is not available there.

Instead, let it start up normally, then in the `ngOnInit` of the app you can do something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({...})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private config: Config) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.platform.is("desktop")) {
      // disable the nav animations:
      this.config.set('navAnimation', null);
      // or disable all animations
      this.config.set('animated', false);
    }
  }
}
```

I've just written this from looking at code snippets so I don't know if setting `navAnimation` to null will work.

Also depending on the structure of your app and how you load, you could probably experiment with moving this into a service or a route guard to make sure its run at the right time no matter how you enter the app?

Comment: Updated snippet to use `is("desktop")` instead of `!is("mobile")`

Comment: this question got unmarked as answer, was it you @shurvirpm? The other week a similar thing happened on a different question, very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes above answer is works almost. but as I want for desktop, so

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.platform.is("desktop")) {
      this.config.set('navAnimation', null);
      this.config.set('animated', false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting it as the answer and upvoting. The reason I didn't use `is("desktop")` because there is also `is("tablet")` and `is("phablet")` which are kind of a grey areas, so I did `!is("mobile")` to cover all medium and large screens. [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/platform.ts#L89) it seems that desktop is simply `!isMobile()` anyway.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand. Thanks for sharing such knowledge.